# Running complicated sql query within CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a new report created in postgres - it should only run if there are 3 completed cases, and then determine an ultimate outcome (pass/fail) based on the individual cases.  Depending on if it passes or fails, different information needs to be displayed.

I have the three main queries that I need, but now I'm at a loss of how to combine them into one.

The main query that contains the conditional logic for a case is here:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Alloc" WHERE "CodeID" = 1 AND "StatusCodeID" IN (2,6)) = 3
THEN 
    --Determine if case passes based on the 3 individual Assessments
    CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Answer" ans
        LEFT JOIN "AnswerOption" ansop ON ansop."AnswerOptionID" = ans."AnswerOptionID"
        LEFT JOIN "QuestionTextInstance" qtxti ON qtxti."QuestionTextInstanceID" = ans."QuestionTextInstanceID"
        LEFT JOIN "Alloc" aloc ON aloc."AllocID" = qtxti."AllocID"
        LEFT JOIN "QuestionText" qtxt ON qtxt."QuestionTextID" = qtxti."QuestionTextID"
        LEFT JOIN "Code" bcode ON aloc."CodeID" = bcode."CodeID" 
        WHERE bcode."CodeID" = 1 AND qtxt."QuestionTextID" = 11 AND ans."Value" = 0) >= 1 --At least 2 must have answered 'Yes'
    THEN 'Passed' --Execute 'Pass.sql'
    ELSE 'Did NOT Pass' --Execute 'NotPass.sql
    END
ELSE 'Report did Not Run'
END
```

This runs correctly and gives the correct results based on the conditions.  However, within the `THEN` and `ELSE` blocks on the inner `CASE` statement, I need to display different information that includes many columns and many joins (which I currently have in different `.sql` files) instead of `Pass`/`Did NOT Pass`, but I can not find a way to implement this because it seems that any query within `THEN` or `ELSE` blocks can only return a single value.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @millimoose I believe it's going to be a `View`

Comment: "it seems that any query within THEN or ELSE blocks can only return a single value" - where did you get this from? (I tried to verify this but SQLFiddle seems to be acting up.) Also, you should be able to back a view with a stored proc, no?

Comment: @millimoose whenever I try to run a query within `THEN` or `ELSE` it barks saying `subquery must return only one column` and then if I limit it to one column it says `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: @millimoose `Also, you should be able to back a view with a stored proc, no?`  I would think you can, but I'm not sure to be honest -  Unfortunately my knowledge of SQL beyond simple queries is scarce; I got thrown into the deepend with this and it is all new to me :]

Comment: I'd consider looking into that then. It's arguably the tool to use to do imperative stuff like control structures, and can certainly return complex data.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in **plain SQL** in various ways. One is with well known composite / row types:

```
SELECT (x).*
FROM (
   SELECT CASE WHEN cond_a_here THEN
                (SELECT t FROM t WHERE x = 1)
          ELSE  (SELECT t FROM t WHERE x = 2) END AS x
   ) sub
```

Note the parentheses in `(x).*`. Those are [required for a composite type to make the syntax unambiguous](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION).

It's *simpler* to understand with **PL/pgSQL**, but you need to *understand* how to handle composite types. I have posted many related answers ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_before()
  RETURNS SETOF t AS
$func$
BEGIN
IF cond_a_here THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 1;
ELSE
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 2;
END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: how would the plain sql be implemented in my query above? I tried Wrapping the whole thing in OP in `select(x).* FROM ( )` and making just the subquery in the `THEN` a composite type, but both ways I still get an error saying that the `subquery must return only one column`

Comment: @Saggio: Well, obviously at least one of your subqueries returns more than one column ...

Comment: @Saggio: You can do that .. like I demonstrate .. by packing multiple columns into a ***single*** composite type and unpacking it on the next query level. And there is nothing about multiple *rows* in your question. The plpgsql version can deal with multiple rows. IN SQL you would put conditions in a `JOIN` clause when joining to a sub-select to get multiple rows from one condition. Not possible with a simple `CASE` statement - or you'd have to aggregate multiple rows into an array and unnest on the next level ...